# Group weekly over several years (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-9.1, datepart

This query groups per week correctly, but sorts strange:

```
SELECT    date_part('week' ,date), SUM(qty)
FROM      hr
WHERE     date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY  date_part('week', date)
ORDER BY  1
```

The result of this query is:

[image: wrong sort]

It should be something like:

[image: correct sort]

How can I identify which year a week belongs to?

Any tip or clue welcome.

TIA,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `to_char()` to format the year **and** week in a single sortable value:

```
SELECT to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'iyyy-iw'), SUM(qty)
FROM hr
WHERE date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'iyyy-iw')
ORDER BY 1
```

The format mask `iyyy` and `iw` use the [ISO week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) which you seem to be expecting (it e.g. assigns 2015-53 for 2016-01-01). If you don't want that you need to switch to `yyyy` and `ww` instead

Comment: Right on track! Changed GROUP BY  to 'iyyy-iw' and it worked as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just concat the year with the weak :

```
SELECT    concat(date_part('year' ,date),date_part('week' ,date)), SUM(qty)
FROM      hr
WHERE     date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY  concat(date_part('year' ,date),date_part('week' ,date))
ORDER BY  1
```

**Edit:** You can try to replace the first column select with this :

```
concat(date_part('year' ,date),
       CASE WHEN date_part('week' ,date) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END,
       date_part('week' ,date))
```

Comment: On the right track! But the sort order remains wrong because the '0' is missing. 20161 comes before 201553. Any tip?

Comment: @sibert Edited the answer